# Can you connect QNAP TS-559 Pro+ to computer with e-sata?

Tags: nas, esata

I have the instructions in front of me and can't work this out.

A QNAP TS-559 Pro+ (NAS Enclosure) has 2 e-sata ports on it, along with 4 USB and 2 Ethernet ports. Does anyone know if it's possible to connect the device to a computer using the e-sata port? Or are the esata ports only for connecting harddrives to the device itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The official site says](http://www.qnap.com/faq_detail.asp?faq_id=650):

Can I connect my PC's USB/eSATA port to NAS via USB or eSATA cable to access the DATA?

No, the USB / eSATA port on the NAS can only be connected to peripheral device. You can only connect to the NAS through the Ethernet network.